# How does SQL server evaluate the cost of an execution plan which contains a user defined function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure which filters based on the result of the `DATEADD` function - My understanding is that this is similar to using user defined functions in that because SQL server cannot store statistics based on the output of that function it has trouble evaluating the cost of an execution plan.

The query looks a little like this:

```
SELECT /* Columns */ FROM
TableA JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id = TableB.join_id
WHERE DATEADD(hour, TableB.HoursDifferent, TableA.StartDate) <= @Now
```

(So its not possible to pre-calculate the outcome of the `DATEADD`)

What I'm seeing is a terrible terrible execution plan which I believe is due to SQL server incorrectly estimating the number of rows being returned from a part of the tree as being 1, when in fact its ~65,000. I have however seen the same stored procedure execute in a fraction of the time when different (not neccessarily less) data is present in the database.

My question is - in cases like these how does the query optimiser estimate the outcome of the function?

**UPDATE:** FYI, I'm more interested in understanding why some of the time I get a good execution plan and why the rest of the time I don't - I already have a pretty good idea of how I'm going to fix this in the long term.

Comment: DATEADD is not a user-defined function. The built-in system functions are often treated differently to user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see the function, but one thing I have seen is burying functions like that in queries can result in poor performance. If you can evaluate some of it beforehand you might be in better shape. For example, instead of

```
WHERE MyDate < GETDATE()
```

Try

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SET @Today = GETDATE()
...
WHERE MyDate < @Today
```

this seems to perform better

Comment: Because SQL has no way to accuratly estimate the number of rows affected when the columns are within a function. When the columns are not within functions it can use the column statistics to get quite good estimates

Answer (score 3):

It's not the costing of the plan that's the problem here. The function on the columns prevent SQL from doing index seeks. You're going to get an index scan or a table scan.

What I'd suggest is to see if you can get one of the columns out of the function, basically see if you can move the function to the other side of the equality. It's not perfect, but it means that at least one column can be used for an index seek.

Something like this (rough idea, not tested) with an index on TableB.HoursDifference, then an index on the join column in TableA

```
DATEDIFF(hour, @Now, TableA.StartDate) >= TableB.HoursDifferent
```

On the costing side, I suspect that the optimiser will use the 30% of the table 'thumb-suck' because it can't use statistics to get an accurate estimate and because it's an inequality. Meaning it's going to guess that 30% of the table will be returned by that predicate.

It's really hard to say anything for sure without seeing the execution plans. You mention an estimate of 1 row and an actual of 65000. In some cases, that's not a problem at all.
http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/22/estimated-rows-actual-rows-and-execution-count/

Comment: It is indeed doing table / index scans, however each table only has a handful of entries (for example 600 or so) - the problem is caused because SQL server ends up doing ~65,000 RDI lookups (on a table which only contains 600 rows!). Again I'm sorry I cant show you an execution plan, but it wouldnt make much sense without knowing the whole context, which like I say involves 10 different tables, a 250 line stored procedure and masses of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

@Kragen,

**Short answer:** If you are doing queries with ten tables, ***get used to it***. You need to learn all about query hints, and a lot more tricks besides.

**Long answer:**

SQL server generally generates excellent query plans for up to about three to five tables only. Once you go beyond that in my experience you are basically going to have to write the query plan yourself, using all the index and join hints. (In addition, Scalar functions seem to get estimated at Cost=Zero, which is just mad.)

The reason is it is just too damn complicated after that. The query optimiser has to decide what to do ***algorithmically***, and there are too many possible combinations for even the brightest geniuses on the SQL Server team to create an algorithm which works truly universally.

They say the optimiser is smarter than you. That may be true. **But you have one advantage.** That advantage is if it doesn't work, you can throw it out and try again! By about the sixth attempt you should have something acceptable, even for a ten-table join, if you know the data. The query optimiser cannot do that, it has to come up with some sort of plan instantly, and it gets no second chances.

My favourite trick is to force the order of the where clause by converting it to a case statement. Instead of:

```
WHERE
predicate1
AND predicate2
AND....
```

Use this:

```
WHERE
case 
when not predicate1 then 0
when not predicate2 then 0
when not .... then 0
else 1 end = 1
```

Order your predicates cheapest to most expensive, and you get an outcome which is logically the same but which SQL server doesn't get to mess around with - it has to do them in the order you say.